# Filter data all entries are empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to filter data from search but all results are displayed on submit button even-

even on 1,2,3 entry
My code is as below code.Pl tell if i am wrong somewhere

Comment: so many problem with code

Comment: If any of the parameters is empty, you'll do `LIKE '%%'` which matches everything.

Answer (score 1):

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rw))
```

remove the space

Comment: Infact i am not getting errors but it literally fetches all data instead of one particular search.So if i search by name abc instead of data related to abc it fetches all records